# How to read a file using readfile on Winapi

Tags: winapi, readfile

I'm learning how to use in Winapi 
And I'm trying to read a file from My Computer
But for some reason it doesn't work ...

```
HANDLE hFile;
//PVOID First_Bytes[2048];
char First_Bytes[2048];
DWORD dbr = 0;
hFile = CreateFile(L"d:\\My-File",GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL , NULL);   
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    printf("Error %x", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
if (ReadFile(hFile, &First_Bytes, 512, &dbr, NULL) == 0) {
    printf("ReadFile error: %x", GetLastError());
    return 1;
}
printf("%s", First_Bytes);
CloseHandle(hFile);
```

The console doesn't print anything.

What am I doing wrong?

- I edited the code and add that errors checks.
  But still consul does not print anything

Comment: Take out `FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED`, and do some error checking.

Comment: Your buffer is an array of 2048 pointers. You don't mean that. You want `char buffer[2048]`, and you have to null terminate. You have to check for errors too.

Comment: I edited the code from scratch, yet I probably missed something(Although not print any error, nothing is printed)

Comment: Your basic mental block is that you don't know how to convert the raw bytes that you read from the file with ReadFile() into something that a human can understand.  ReadFile() is not a substitute for fscanf().  Since the file doesn't appear to contain anything that's suitable for human eyes, most definitely not a string, the only proper way to display something recognizable is by showing the hex representation of the bytes.  Use printf() with the %x format specifier in a loop.

Answer (score 2):

The logical conclusion is that the first byte in your file is a zero. You treat the buffer as a null-terminated string, and so nothing is printed.

Do note that there is no guarantee that your buffer is null terminated so you potentially have undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is the beginning of the file: "00 00 00 1C 66 74 79 70 69 73 6F 6D 00 00 00 01 69 73 6F 6D 61 76 63 31 69 73 6F 36 00 0B C1 A7 6D 6F 6F 76 00 00 00 6C 6D 76 68 64" , From what you are saying because of that 3 first bytes are 0 then the program treats them as EOF? How can I fix this thing? PRINTF always relate to zeros as the end of a string.

Comment: The file isn't a text file. What is it?

Comment: What does it matter what type of file?
It is not just supposed to open it and read it? (The hexadecimal value)

Comment: Your code treats the file as text. If you want to treat as binary, and display hex, why are you using `%s`? I just answered the question you asked.

Comment: Sorry,I did not explain myself well enough question then i edited my question, by the way when I try to open a file TEXT is really no problem reading (it happens all entries) (The only problem this identification of the EOF as I outlined the question)

Comment: It doesn't work that way. You ask a question, we answer it. You don't to to change the question after it has been answered. I reverted your edit. If you want to ask a different question, that needs a new question. This one has been dealt with.

Comment: Now, it's nothing to do with EOF. Files don't contain EOF marks. Your problem is that you are treating binary as text. If you want to read binary, read into an array of `unsigned char` and print that as hex. No use for `%s` when doing so.

Comment: "by the way when I try to open a file TEXT is really no problem reading" You can read text with a text viewer. But above data won't work with a text editor like Notepad. Text output stops when it sees zero (zero is END OF LINE, not END OF FILE)  Use this to print bytes: `for(int i = 0; i < dbr; i++) printf("%02x ", First_Bytes[i]);`